# Is this the correct way to genericise a function for floats/doubles

Tags: c++, templates, generics

In my function:

```
template <typename T>
T lerpMidway(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    T result;
    result = (b - a) * 0.5 + a;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    lerpMidway(4.f, 6.f);
}
```

If I pass float values to this function I think the 0.5 will promote all the other floats to doubles, and then convert it back to float when it's time to return it.

I tried the line:

```
result = (b - a) * decltype(a)(0.5) + a;
```

and it got rid of the compiler message saying double to float possible loss of data, but here if "a" is a float, and I initialise it with a double, there's no conversion happening? I could also initialise it with a 0.5f and it wouldn't make a difference?

Comment: What *is* the problem with the modified code? Does it give you incorrect results? Do you suspect it will give you incorrect results sometimes?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but for native types (like `int`, `float`, etc.) there's really no use in passing them by `const` references. Pass them by `const` *value* instead.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not entirely comfortable with how decltype works and initialising primitive data types in brackets. If I say for example int(6.0) I assume it'll do a conversion, but I was wondering if decltype(a)(6.0) will do a conversion, and whether it doesn't matter in that case if I type 6.0 or 6.0f.

Comment: Using `decltype` here does not make much sense since the type of `a` is already known. Why don't you just write `* T{0.5}`?

Comment: @Some programmer dude, passing primitives by *const value* is not really necessary either because they're just copies anyway (so no point in protecting them by using *const*).

Comment: @dsp_user If they are not modified inside the function, the compiler might be able to do some optimizations or otherwise generate better code. Making the arguments `const` *guarantees* that, instead of the compiler having to deduce it.

Comment: Ok, I guess that could be a valid point :)

Comment: Because "The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater range and precision than that required by the type" ([expr.pre/5](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.pre#5)), even if you cast `0.5` to `float`, the implementation may evaluate the arithmetic expression in greater range and precision (for example, `double`), and then remove extra range and precision when initializing `result` with the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, `0.5` has type `double`, and `0.5f` has type `float`. There is no way to specify a literal of a type which is a template parameter. A cast is acceptable in such cases.

I recommend `static_cast` rather than a functional style cast. `decltype` is unnecessary, the type in question already has a name, `T`.

Thus, `static_cast<T>(0.5)` is perfectly OK.

From the purely abstract point of view, there's a conversion from `double` to `float` (or whatever type `T` denotes). In practice, this conversion is a no-op. From the compiler's perspective, it's a simple case of constant folding.

Comment: Is the static_cast essentially the same as declval(a)(0.5)? Leaving aside that I passed the argument by reference. That is, in both cases the data type of float or double is decided at compile time?

Comment: @Zebrafish Yes it is essentially the same in this case. `static_cast` is more clear and visible, and should be preferred. `T(0.5)` is the same thing too.

Answer (score 4):

> there's no conversion happening?

If `T` is a float then there is a conversion happening. `0.5` is a double constant. Casting it is a conversion. That's from the pure language sense.

Only issue is, that you don't convert to a `T`, but to a `T const&` (that's what `decltype` gives). Essentially, you materialize a temporary.

Passing by value will avoid that, and make `decltype(a)` resolve to `T`. If `T` is a `float`, you'll obtain the cast `float(0.5)`. That in all likelihood will resolve to the same constant as `0.5f`.

Comment: I didn't think about the fact that it's a reference. So decltype(a) you say will materialise a temporary, meaning there is now another copy of a? Also, when you say there's a conversion from double to float, that's not in the case of decltype(a)(0.5) right? There's no conversion there?

Comment: @Zebrafish - `decltype` doesn't materialize anything. It gives a type. If that type is an lvalue reference that you cast to, *that* materializes a temporary. Simply because the cast to an lvalue reference must be an lvalue. And I do believe I said there *is* a conversion. A cast is a conversion. You cast.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding, when I did decltype(a)(0.5) the warning from my compiler about conversion from double to float was removed, so I assumed the cast was removed, and it somehow decided at compile time which appropriate data type (float or double) it was going to use

Comment: @Zebrafish - A cast is an **explicit conversion**. You compiler warned you about an implicit conversion, because it resulted in a narrowing conversion later on. When you assigned to `result`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case of the (admittedly unlikely) case where T is a volatile float, I might be inclined to write the function something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto lerpMidway(const T& a, const T& b) -> std::decay_t<T>
{
    using type = std::decay_t<T>;
    const auto factor = type(0.5);

    type result;

    result = (b - a) * factor + a;

    return result;
}
```

Since `decltype(a)` would then be `const volatile float&` and you can't cast the `double` 0.5 to that.